# Can i get all posts from an event's feed using Facebook Graph API?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i'm having some troubles trying to get all posts from an event's feed. My code is something like this:

1- Get the posts from feed. It only returns the first 10 posts from the event feed

```
FB.api(eventID + '/feed?access_token=' + token, function (response){
});
```

2 - The response has a paging "next" parameter but when a try to search the next page i get an empty JSON object.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the event feed has more than 10 results? In the response you will always get the `previous` and `next` paging values, although there might be no more results available.

You could also play around with `limit` parameter (the default value is 25)

Check an example [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=955223107829035%2Ffeed%3Flimit%3D5&version=v2.2&#_=__).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yes, the event has more than 10 posts. Using your example when i click on the "next" link of the first page it works fine and i get five more results but when i click it again it returns an empty json object. I have no idea why we can only retrieve 10 results and i couldn't find anything about it in the documentation. Even if you try with limit 25 it returns 10 or less. I will keep looking.